# Issues app uber driver lenovo k6 in 6.0.1

Tags: uber-api

Well i have 2 issues already using the app uber driver.. 1) The screen sometimes looks black and dont let me in the app. 2) At the top where it comes "on line" flashes the blue sector always. Any solution for this problems?

Answer (score 0):

as was mentioned on your tweet (https://twitter.com/UberDevelopers/status/833828577686671360) this is not an Uber API issue. Your best bet for this potential Uber driver app bug is to reach out to Uber via help.uber.com or via @uber_support.